# Firebase scheduled function not triggering

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a function scheduled to be triggered at 11AM EST.

As you can see in the code below I have it set to run at 11AM `.schedule("0 11 * * *")` on an EST timezone `.timeZone("America/New_York")`.

I am currently on this timezone and waited for the function to trigger and nothing happened.

The function is deployed properly to my Firebase project. Just curious if I'm doing something wrong here. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// function expires all EST timezone passes
exports.expirePassesEST = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 11 * * *")
  .timeZone("America/New_York")
  .onRun(async () => {
    // get all passes (passes & covers) that have a timezone offset of 240 (EST offset)
    const fastPassesRef = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("fastpasses")
      .where("timezoneOffset", "===", 240)
      .get();

    const coversRef = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("covers")
      .where("timezoneOffset", "==", 240)
      .get();

    // loop thorugh each fast pass and cover, and expire it
    fastPassesRef.forEach((fastPass) =>
      fastPass.ref.update({ status: "expired", expiredTimestamp: new Date() })
    );

    coversRef.forEach((cover) =>
      cover.ref.update({ status: "expired", expiredTimestamp: new Date() })
    );
  });
```

Comment: "I waited for the function to trigger and nothing happened" => How dso you know it didn't run? What do you see in the log? Any error?

Comment: Also, is this your entire and complete Cloud Function code? Note that you don't [initialize an admin app instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app). This is most probably the problem but since you don't share any log or error we cannot confirm. Another problem is the fact that you incorrectly terminate your Cloud Function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't share any error log in your question so it is difficult to help you. However, by just reading your code we can detect two major problems:

1. You don't [initialize an admin app instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app). You should do `admin.initializeApp();`.
2. You incorrectly terminate your Cloud Function: you need to wait that all the asynchronous operations are completed before indicating to the Cloud Functions platform that it can shut down the Cloud Function instance. More details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions). For that, since you are using loops to call several asynchronous updates, you need to use `Promise.all()` or a batched write.

The following should work:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); 
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.expirePassesEST = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("0 11 * * *")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(async () => {
        // get all passes (passes & covers) that have a timezone offset of 240 (EST offset)
        const fastPassesSnapshot = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("fastpasses")
            .where("timezoneOffset", "===", 240)
            .get();

        const coversSnapshot = await admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("covers")
            .where("timezoneOffset", "==", 240)
            .get();

        const promises = [];

        fastPassesSnapshot.forEach((fastPass) =>
            promises.push(fastPass.ref.update({ status: "expired", expiredTimestamp: new Date() }))
        );

        coversSnapshot.forEach((cover) =>
            promises.push(cover.ref.update({ status: "expired", expiredTimestamp: new Date() }))
        );

        return Promise.all(promises);

    });
```

Comment: Hey @devon66h, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?